# jQuery issue with child elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't understand why the last part of code affects the second `div` and not the first like the first bit does. In addition, all of the other content that was there disappears, which is not the desired behavior. The book I am reading doesn't explain why the second div is affected and not the first. Why is this happening to the second and not the first?. I assumed `div:last-child` would alter the first `div` as it's considered the immediate parent?.

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('div:first-child').text('This is the first child');   
  $('div:last-child').text('I\'ve changed this!'); 
});
```

HTML

```
<div id=”myfirstdiv”>
  <strong class=”changemytext”>some name</strong>
  <p class=”changemytext”>Some text<p>
  <strong>another name</strong>
  <p>More text<p>
</div>

<div id=”myseconddiv”>
  <strong class=”changemytext”>some name</strong>
  <p class=”changemytext”>Some text<p>
  <strong>another name</strong>
  <p>More text<p>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: What you are trying to do here ?

Comment: I was under the belief, only those elements would be affected, as I've said above but ok, first element of first parent changes, as does last of second but the rest of the content has also gone. I thought the first and last elements of the first div would be affected only.

Comment: Thanks Cody for simplifying my code.

Answer (score 1):

first-child causes you to hit the first option available, last-child causes you to hit the last one (the second in this case.  If you didn't add the pseudo selector, they would both hit both of them.

Answer (score 1):

I will simply translate your selectors:

```
//$(The divs that the first child of their parents).text('This is the first child');
$('div:first-child').text('This is the first child');   

//$(The divs that the last child of their parents).text('I\'ve changed this!');
$('div:last-child').text('I\'ve changed this!');
```

Answer (score 1):

The `:first-child Selector` basically selects all elements that are the first child of their parent.

and the `:last-child Selector` selects all elements that are the last child of their parent.

Here, the parent is the `body` and first div  is the **first-child** here and the second div is the **last-child** here and you are getting the expected result.

What you are trying to achieve needs to be done like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('div :first-child').text('This is the first child');
    $('div :last-child').text('I\'ve changed this!');
});
```

Comment: Ah that's it!. Thanks. I had thought, the first div was the parent, so hence my confusion!. Many thanks!.